# How to remove certain html content?

Tags: php, html, string, web-scraping

I have the following content

```
<div>
  <span>
    Test B
  </span>
  <div>
    Test C
  </div>
</div>
```

And i need to remove  content

```
<span>
        Test B
</span>
```

Required output :

```
<div>
  <div>
    Test C
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Why u can't try it with str_replace

Comment: @kannan the content inside <span> tag may change thats why.

Comment: So you want to remove the content whatever inside the the span right.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. Show some code, etc.

Comment: @kannan yes. MikeWu this is my hom work for tommorow pls help me dude :(

Comment: do you have to use php ? or you can use javascript ? and check my answer , iam using php in that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your html structre is fixed

you can then use `preg_replace`

```
$html = preg_replace('#<span>.*?</span>#s','',$html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = ' place your html content';
$replacedHtml = preg_replace('/<span>.*?<\/span>/','',$html);
 ?>
```